# How can I use a variable to choose which Serial port to interact with?

Tags: serial

In my use case I have multiple devices connected to the serial ports of an arduino. Currently I write to them using `Serial1.write()`, `Serial2.write()`, etc.

How can I choose the port programmatically, for example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numDevices; i++){
  Serial[i].write();
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? ... what errors did you get?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors because, as stated, I know how to write it 'hard-coded' but not the way I want. I didn't try Serial[i] because that's obviously wrong, but I can't find any docs on how to write to a variable pin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use an array of pointers to the actual serial ports. For
example, on an Arduino Mega:

```cpp
const size_t PORTS_COUNT = 4;
const HardwareSerial *ports[PORTS_COUNT] = {
    &Serial, &Serial1, &Serial2, &Serial3
};

void setup() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < PORTS_COUNT; i++)
        ports[i]->begin(9600);
}
```